# How to get detailed exception in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am using powershell to copy folder and files inside. Below is the command im using

```
Copy-Item "C:\source" "C:\destination" -recurse
```

i get error

> Copy-Item : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be le
>   characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Copy-Item "C:\source" "C:\destination" -recurse
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (component.json:FileInfo) [Copy-Item], PathTooLongException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CopyDirectoryInfoItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

i understood the error, but i wanted to know which file is having issue so i can fix it. The Error doesnt show the actual file

I tried using

```
$error[0]|format-list -force
```

it shows detail stack trace but it doesn't show the file path

Comment: can you simply append `-Verbose` to your `Copy-Item` command, although it might be a lot of console noise I expect you would see the offending file just before the exception.

Answer (score 0):

The `$error` array consists of `ErrorRecords`. You can see what properties and methods are in an `ErrorRecord` by: `$error|get-member`. Among other things you'll see the `ErrorDetails, Exception, and TargetObject` properties. In many cases one or more of those properties will have additional useful information.

In your case `TargetObject` is a good bet. I tried to copy a non-existent file on my system and `TargetObject` was set to the invalid file name. To view you can use: `$error[0].TargetObject|select *`.

Answer (score 0):

The `$error` array consists of `ErrorRecords`. You can see what properties and methods are in an `ErrorRecord` by: `$error|get-member`. Among other things you'll see the `ErrorDetails, Exception, and TargetObject` properties. In many cases one or more of those properties will have additional useful information.

In your case `TargetObject` is a good bet. I tried to copy a non-existent file on my system and `TargetObject` was set to the invalid file name. To view you can use: `$error[0].TargetObject|select *`.

I have a script in my profile that outputs `$error[0]` as well as some of those properties listed above. Sometimes `$error[0].exception` will have an "inner exception", so my script checks to see if that exists and dumps that as well.